# How can I remove handlers for 4xx / 5xx errors in GoDaddy?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP entry point which returns a json object (using `json_encode`) and returns a certain status code among (500, 400, 410, 409, 404, 200).

However, when I hit the page using a REST client AND the response status is not 200, I get an error page being rendered (text/html - **yes, I did not forget including an Accept: application/json header**).

How do I specify to REMOVE ANY ERROR PAGE handler in GoDaddy? I care about this only in a subdomain / subfolder (http://subdomain.example.com/ or http://example.com/subdomain/).

I figure I must do it in a .htaccess file but: what must I put inside to override the handlers?

**Edit**: NO! It is an IIS. I had to use a WebConfig

Answer (score 1):

You can place these `ErrorDocument` directives in the `DocumentRoot` of subdomain to **reset all the handlers set earlier**:

```
ErrorDocument 500 default
ErrorDocument 400 default
ErrorDocument 410 default
ErrorDocument 409 default
ErrorDocument 409 default
ErrorDocument 200 default
```

Comment: this would disable the pages and let me total control over the content?

Comment: This will disable all previously set `ErrorDocument` and then you can have your rewrite rules to route them.

Comment: Actually I figured the host they assigned me was an IIS :s. So I solved it in an IIS way.